# Flutter Android Debug Bridge (ADB) over different network on VSCODE

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, adb

I am using VScode for flutter development.

I am also using "ADB Interface for VScode" to debug the coding over the same network wirelessly.

When I am not at home, I remote into my desktop to do some work but I see that most of the ADB only works on the same network.

Does anyone know how to use the ADB over a different network (for example, cellular network on your phone).

**Bit more clarification: User Scenario**

**When I am away from my desktop in the same house**, I use the "Remote Desktop" app on my Android tablet to remote into my Windows Desktop to work and of course, because my phone is in the same network, I can debug it using ADB without any issue.

**When I am outside of my house,** ADB doesn't work and wondering if there are any ways to connect the Android Debug. Of course, I am using my android tablet to remote into my desktop using the Remote Desktop app.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems similar to: [How to connect ADB over 3G/4G?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25902/3573), but you may want to clarify where the Android dev phone and development PC is located when you "remote into desktop".

Comment: It looks like you've [modified your question on Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245848/3573) to match this one. You should still clarify how you are remoting to your Flutter dev PC as if you are using the same Android device as what you are adb connecting to, I'm not sure how you can debug at the same time unless you are using Samsung DeX which isn't clearly specified.

Comment: adb is a plain text connection (like telnet) so using it over the internet makes your phone attackable while you are connected. This is the reason why by default adb is only used locally via USB or in a local (trusted) network.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the reply. Sorry about lack of clarification. I added a bit more info :)